# JavaScriptのDateオブジェクトに対して、JSON.stringify()メソッドに対するベストプラクティスを教えてください

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptのDateオブジェクトの扱いについて質問します。
ブラウザ側からサーバにPOSTする時にデータをJSON化して送付することをと試みています。
しかし、JSON.stringify()メソッドにかけると【協定世界時（UTC）】に置き換えられてしまいます。

```
var someDay = new Date(2014,12,2);
console.log(someDay); --- > Wed Dec 03 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (東京 (標準時))
console.log(JSON.stringify(someDay)); --> "2014-12-02T15:00:00.000Z"
```

サーバサイドでは、この挙動への対処を行いたくないので、ブラウザ側（JS側）で挙動に対する対処を行いたいと考えております。その際のベストプラクティスを教示頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: 「サーバサイドでは、この挙動への対処を行いたくない」だけではなく、「サーバがどのような形式を受け付けるのか」も書いたほうが、より具体的なアドバイスが貰えるかと思います。

Comment: おっしゃるとおりです。気をつけます。わかりにくくてすいませんでした。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

タイムゾーン表記は処理系によってロケールに依存してしまい、上手く動かない場合もあります。
コンピュータの日付は 1970 年 1 月 1 日 00:00:00 UTC からの経過ミリ秒で管理出来ます。
この値さえあれば、どの時刻オフセットに対しても計算で Date クラスに戻す事が出来ますし、おおよそそのプログラミング言語でも取り扱えます。JavaScript であれば `getTime()` で取得出来ます。

```
var now = new Date();
console.log(now); // Tue Dec 16 2014 14:50:56 GMT+0900 (東京 (標準時))
var tm = now.getTime(); // 1418709056398

now = new Date(tm);
console.log(now); // Tue Dec 16 2014 14:50:56 GMT+0900 (東京 (標準時))
```

JSONという表記に拘る必要はありません。どうしてもJSONという事であれば

```
{
    "time": 1418709056398
}
```

の様に `getTime()` した値を保持するのが良いと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。経過ミリ秒で表現するのがブレがなくよいと思いました。採用させて頂きました。

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify には[「toJSON メソッドがあれば toJSON() の返す値を採用する」](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) というものがあります。
これを活用すると、JSONにおける表現をピンポイントでカスタマイズすることができます。
以下のように書くこともできるでしょう。

```
var someDay = new Date(2014,12,2);

// someData の toJSON メソッドを別のメソッドでオーバーライドしておく
someDay.toJSON = Date.prototype.toGMTString;

// JSON.stringify の結果が変化する
console.log(JSON.stringify(someDay)); // "Thu, 01 Jan 2015 15:00:00 GMT"
```

このやり方は Dateオブジェクトに限らず利用できます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。オーバーライド行う方法とても勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

TimeZone safeでなくなるので、色々問題を含みますが、

```
var someDay = new Date(); 
someDay.setHours(someDay.getHours() - someDay.getTimezoneOffset() / 60);

var someDayJSON = JSON.stringify(someDay);
console.log(someDayJSON);
```

こうすると、質問への直接的な解決方法になるかと思います。
＃結果のJSONが末尾Zが付いているのに、UTCでない時刻が送信されることにご留意ください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。意図した解決策です。よく考えるとUTCでなかったりして落とし穴があるものになってしまいますね･･･。

Answer (score 0):

もしDateを何らかの文字列形式にしたいということであれば、[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)のformatを使うのが簡単です。

```
moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

で`2014-12-25`になります。詳細は[ドキュメント](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)を見てください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。Moment.jsは便利ですね！紹介ありがとうございます。